# how to plot frequency domain of only a portion of wav and do variable smoothing?

Tags: python, plotly, signal-processing, wav

premise: I need to plot the frequency domain of an audio sample, I know nothing about signal processing and very little of python I followed few examples and it is kinda working using fft and fftfreq.

all audio are about 30sec and contain 2 equal very short impulse sound but I am plotting in the browser so I need to get a very low number of points just for the relevant portion.

my problems are 3 :

1st to keep the datapoints to a low number I pick only the relevant seconds by hand which is ugly, what is the right way ?

```
    samplerate, dataw= wavfile.read('x.wav')
    dataw = dataw[(round(24.98*samplerate)):(round(24.98*samplerate)+32767)]
```

2nd to smooth more the higher frequencies my friend in matlab chunked the data so has different smoothing as the frequencies get higher:

```
%% we identify three portions of the spectrum (although they could be more) 
%% and we smooth them with different smoothing factors to improve readibility

    smooth_spect_1 = fastsmooth(Spectrum_dB(1:70), 5, 1, 1); 
    smooth_spect_2 = fastsmooth(Spectrum_dB(71:700), 7, 1, 1);         
    smooth_spect_3 = fastsmooth(Spectrum_dB(701:end), 41 , 1, 1);        
    total_smooth = [smooth_spect_1; smooth_spect_2; smooth_spect_3];
    plot(f, total_smooth);
```

in python I am using one savgol_filter for the whole thing, which is ok for the low frequencies but not enough for the high, how do it get a similar result ?

3rd how do I convert the y axis in db ?

the whole thing :

```
    def doFFT(dataw: ndarray, samplerate: int): 
        dataw = dataw[(round(24.98*samplerate)):(round(24.98*samplerate)+32767)]
        datafft = rfft(dataw)  
        #Get the absolute value of real and complex component:
        fftabs = abs(datafft)     
        freqs = rfftfreq(dataw.shape[0], 1/(samplerate))  
        smoothed = savgol_filter(fftabs,  10,  3)  
     
        return [ freqs[:int(freqs.size/2)].tolist() , smoothed[:int(freqs.size/2)].tolist() ]
```

I spit this out in json to plot in the browser with plotly:

[image: here is current result]

Thank you!!

Comment: 1) if you do this only for a few samples - you are doing it the right way, no need to write something complicated for such a thing as cutting some waves

Comment: 2nd and 3rd should be separate questions, with all relevant code and best some images what's wrong (e.g. what do you mean by "not enough for a high").